# Using foreach on an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I used the `foreach` loop like in the following, would it run? I understand that `foreach` is meant for arrays but seeing as objects in JavaScript are similar to associative arrays, I figured it might be possible.
*Note: This is not active production code. This is just an example of what I'm trying to do.*

```
var target = {};
target.variable.x == 'y';
target.variable.x.foreach(function(e, i, a) {console.log('something happens')});
```

Comment: `Would it run?` Run it and you'll find out.

Comment: Rather than asking you just try and find out

Comment: Note that your example isn't suggesting iteration of an `Object`, but of a `String` -- `'y'`. But, no, `forEach()` isn't defined for `Object`s (or strings) by default.

Comment: Sorry guys. Reason I asked instead of simply testing it was because I'm not used to working with objects in JavaScript. So, I wasn't sure if it just couldn't be done, or if it had to be done a certain way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
    console.log("[" + index + "] = " + element);
}

var target = {};
target.variable = {};
target.variable.x = ["y"]; // Array!

var OBJ = target.variable.x;

OBJ.forEach(logArrayElements); // "[0] = y"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

...exactly, says: `Array`. For Objects this might help

```
var target = {};
target.variable = {};
target.variable.x = 'y';

var OBJ = target.variable;


for(var key in OBJ){
  if(OBJ.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    console.log( key +' '+ OBJ[key]);  // x y
  }
}
```